# Unordered_map iterator invalidation

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map

i have this iterator loop,

```
typedef  boost::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, NavigationNode> NodesMap;
NodesMap nodes;
for (NodesMap::iterator it= nodes.begin(); it != nodes.end() ; ++it)
{

  if(it->second.type == NavigationNodeType_Walkable)
  {
    ConnectNode(&it->second);
  }

}
```

ConnectNode function seems to be invalidating the iterator. It pushes new elements inside the NavigationNode and modifies existing members of the NavigationNode.

i have two questions

- Is passing it->second as pointer bad?
- What's the best way to iterate through this container?

thank you.

**edit:**

does accessing container's elements like this

```
   nodes[intpair(x, y)]
```

inside ConnectNode function would cause this problem?

**edit2**
yes it does.

Why is that? and How would i get around it?

Comment: What evidence do you have that the iterator is invalidated?

Comment: Iterators to an unordered map are only invalidated if the container itself is modified, either by erasing the element to which you had the iterator, or when rehashing occurs.

Comment: i suspect it, when i comment out ConnectNode function it works fine.

Comment: Great, then just comment it out :-)

Comment: if this is not a iterator invalidation. do you know anything that would cause this?

Comment: @mikbal: It sounds like `ConnectNode` does something to `nodes`, but without seeing the definition of that function we can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is passing it->second as pointer bad?

  It depends on what the function that takes the pointer itself does. Taken in isolation, there is nothing inherently wrong with passing a pointer.
- What's the best way to iterate through this container?

  The way that you are using is fine. Using `begin()` and `end()` to iterate is pretty standard.

So I think the problem must be with the `ConnectNode`, and it is likely that you do not have an iterator invalidation problem, but something else.

"does accessing container's elements like this"

```
nodes[intpair(x, y)]
```

This will add a new entry to the map is one with key `intpair(x,y)` doesn't exist, so yes, this could mess up the iteration. You can avoid this by checking if the element exists for that key before accessing with the `[]` operator.

Comment: accessing nodes map inside ConnectNode function caused it.(check edit)
do you know why?

Comment: @mikbal accessing the nodes like that would add new elements if they don't exist, so yes, it could mess things up.

Comment: ok. i should first check if it exists, then try to access it.
thank you. that was it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your update, `ConnectNode` can modify the map you're iterating over.

```
nodes[intpair(x, y)]
```

If that key doesn't already exist in the map, then a new element will be inserted. That might cause the map to be rehashed, invalidating all iterators.

To avoid modifying the map, then you could use `find()` or `at()`. `find()` will indicate whether the key exists via its return value, and `at()` will throw if the key doesn't exist.

If you do need to add new elements to the map during `ConnectNode`, then things are rather more tricky. You could perhaps put them in a separate container, and then add them to `nodes` after your loop.